# How to right align text in custom form textfield in Drupal 7?

Tags: 7, forms

I have a custom form with a textfield that takes numeric values (temperature). I want to right-align the text typed in textfield. Should I use CSS or is there a Drupal attribute to do this?

Here's the present code:

```
$form['temperature'] = array(
            '#type' => 'textfield',
            '#title' => 'Answer',
            '#description' => 'Enter temperature in &deg; Fahrenheit',
            '#required' => TRUE,
            '#size' => 6,
            '#maxlength' => 6,
            '#field_suffix' => '&deg; Fahrenheit',
            '#element_validate' => array('_myform_temperature_validate'),
        );
```

Comment: I think you should just add you custom [class](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--topics--forms_api_reference.html/7#attributes).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no Form API property to align the text. You will have to resort to CSS, 'text-align: right' will do it.

Comment: Precisely that's what I wanted to know. :)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, add a custom class, or use an existing one. You can add custom CSS styles to your form using [#attached](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--topics--forms_api_reference.html/7#attached).

Comment: If I need to use CSS, I'd be comfortable using #attributes to assign CSS classes as @kalabro has commented above, and let my module/theme CSS file handle the class.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand well, I guess that you can use the "settings" array to control your alignment. I found this example: [Drupal 7 Field API Simple Example - Digging Deeper](http://public-action.org/content/drupal-7-field-api-drupal-7-field-api-simple-example-digging-deeper).

```
'settings' => array(
              'container' => array(
                  'float' => 'right',
                  'class' => '',
                  'inline_style' => '',
                  array('background' =>
                      array('image' => ''),
                  ),
              ),
...
```

Comment: Which `settings` array are you referring to? I have no problem using CSS. I simply wanted to know if I could code it with some Drupal option and let Drupal handle the CSS